# How to append a string to each word in a words list and assign the new words list to a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file

This seems like a trivial question, but I have not been able to come up with an elegant solution for this.

I have a list of words assigned to the environment variable `A`. I have another variable `b` of which string value should be concatenated with each word in the words list of `A` to get a new words list assigned to the environment variable `C`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
@echo off
set A=test batch
set b=ing

for %%a in (%A%) do (
    set C=%%a%b%
)

echo %C%
Pause
```

The command line `echo %C%` should output `testing batching`, but output with this code is just `batching`.

How to append string value of variable `b` to each word in words list of variable `A` to get a new words list assigned to the variable `C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for command **SET** output on running in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window `set /?` explains on an **IF** and a **FOR** example similar to code in question when and how to use [delayed environment variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "A=test batch"
set "b=ing"
set "C="

for %%I in (%A%) do set "C=!C! %%I%b%"

rem Remove the space character at beginning.
set "C=%C:~1%"
echo %C%

endlocal
pause
```

All `!` in strings are interpreted by the code above as begin/end of a delayed expanded environment variable reference resulting in wrong processing as it can be seen by using `set "b=ing!"` in fourth line or even more worse using `set "A=!test! batch"` in third line.

There is another solution which avoids the usage of delayed environment variable expansion and for that reason is working also for strings containing one or more exclamation marks.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "A=test batch"
set "b=ing"
set "C="

for %%I in (%A%) do call set "C=%%C%% %%I%b%"

rem Remove the space character at beginning.
set "C=%C:~1%"
echo %C%

endlocal
pause
```

The environment variable `C` is referenced with `%%` on both sides resulting in **FOR** command line being processed by Windows command processor to the following before execution of command **FOR**:

```
  for %I in (test batch) do call set "C=%C% %Iing"
```

The command **CALL** results in one more processing of `set "C=%C% %Iing"` before execution of command **SET** on which `%C%` is replaced by current value of environment variable `C`.

See also:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/)